# algorithms an pseudocode first year IT

Tags: algorithm, logic, computer-science, pseudocode

I am faced with a question that goes like this:

> Write pseudocode that allows a user to repeatedly enter positive
>   integers until an odd number is entered. It would then print the sum
>   of all numbers entered (excluding the odd number).

Example: given that the user enters `2 24 16 8 7` the program would print 50.

I would like to get some feedback on my algorithm for this problem.

```
1. Start
2. Declare int number,n,sum=0
3. Do
4. Input number
5. Read number
6. n=number%2
7. If (n==0) then sum+=number
8. while (n==0)
9. If(n==1) then display number and print sum
10. Endif
11. Endwhile
11. Stop
```

Comment: There's no loop here. This will read at most 2 numbers then stop.

Comment: How can i correct this.

Comment: Do you have examples of the preferred format of pseudo-code for your course? If so, look for loops and see how they are presented. Meanwhile, pretend you are a really stupid computer, try to follow your code with pencil and paper, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Bugs**

You need to move a copy of line 5 (**n=number%2**) inside of the loop - right now you've got an infinite loop if `n == 0` because `n` is not modified inside of the loop

**Possible Bugs**

Some languages will return a negative value on the modulo operation if the dividend or divisor is negative, so you may want to take the absolute value of the remainder (**n=abs(number%2)**)

**Formatting / Syntax**

This is a case where you should use a [do while](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop) loop - this will let you eliminate lines 3 through 5

Indent the stuff inside the loop

Comment: This helped me understand what was going on much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using do while loop and i made some changes to your algorithm. i think it solves your problem.

```
1. Start
2. Declare int number,n,sum=0
3. Do
4.   Input number
5.   Read number
6.   n=number%2
7.   If (n==0) then sum=sum+number
8. while (n==0)
9. print sum
10.Stop
```

Comment: thank you again for the help, i really do appreciate it.Its been hard for me to make the transition from business an economic principles into IT.

Answer (score 0):

`number+sum` should be `sum+=number`because you need to add the value of the number to the sum, the `number+sum` isn't assigned anywhere.

Comment: would this change display an print statement in anyway>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below two inside the loop

```
6. n=number%2
7. If (n==0) then sum+=number
```

or else it will be an infinite loop or until some one enters an odd number.